# cannot access simple http server

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I created a simple Simple http server using

python -m SimpleHTTPServer

I can access it via my laptop or through my phone but when it is acessed through another location it shows Webpage not available or when I try to access it through my browser's VPN it also gives an ERROR: Requested url could not be retrieved..
What seems to be the issue ?
I'm pasting the output of wget here

```
   wget 192.168.43.171:8000
   --2016-08-15 17:40:06--  http://192.168.43.171:8000/
   Connecting to 192.168.43.171:8000... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Length: 242 [text/html]
   Saving to: ‘index.html’

   index.html          100%[====================>]     242  --.-KB/s   in       0s     

   2016-08-15 17:40:06 (28.8 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [242/242]
```

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/548300/how-can-make-a-web-server-publicly-accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPv4 addresses starting with 192.168 are part of the local network block.
You cannot access them outside your local network.

See also: http://xkcd.com/742

Comment: Cute, but a simple link to https://xkcd.com/742 at the end of your answer is probably better than embedding that stuff...